# Executar uma função após o status de compra confirmada

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Galera, estou com um e-commerce em mãos usando o CMS WordPress + WooCommerce + PagSeguro(Versão do Claudio Sanches) e gostaria de realizar uma mudança no BD após a compra ser confirmada.

Essa mudança seria simples, somente trocar um campo dentro do usuário.

Resumindo, atualmente preciso descobrir se existe alguma função do woocommerce que executa após a compra ser confirmada. (No caso o meu produto é digital)

Alguém sabe uma solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está procurando por uma [*Action*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), em especial a [`woocommerce_payment_complete`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#2485). [Aqui](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) você encontra uma (extensa) lista com todos os *hooks* que o woocommerce disponibiliza.

Basicamente, você cria um *action* do tipo

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','meu_metodo' );
```

e, obviamente, cria o seu método

```
function meu_metodo(){
    # code...
}
```

e o seu método `meu_metodo()` será executado toda vez que essa ação (pagamento completo) acontecer. [Aqui](http://squelchdesign.com/web-design-newbury/woocommerce-detecting-order-complete-on-order-completion/) tem um artigo que detalha um pouco mais sobre ações que podem acontecer junto ao pagamento.

Comment: Estou até sem palavras para te agradecer cara! Hahaha, valeu!